# NHibernate and recursive query filter

Tags: nhibernate, recursion, filter, criteria

I have a problem with tree structure and applying filters to the tree root. I need to create a query by using the NHibernate criteria, which will apply filter to the very root of the tree (there can be more than one tree and I need to provide the ID of the root). In plain sql this would look sth like:

```
WITH    c ( Node, Parent, Child, LEVEL )
      AS ( SELECT   N.CatalogNodeId ,
                    N.ParentCatalogNodeId ,
                    N.CatalogNodeId ,
                    CAST(0 AS BIGINT)
           FROM     CatalogNode N
           WHERE    N.ParentCatalogNodeId IS NULL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   C.Node ,
                    N.ParentCatalogNodeId ,
                    N.CatalogNodeId ,
                    C.Level + 1
           FROM     CatalogNode N
                    JOIN c ON C.Child = n.ParentCatalogNodeId
         )
SELECT  
        c.Child
FROM    c
        JOIN dbo.CatalogItem CI ON Ci.CatalogNodeId = c.Child
        JOIN dbo.Item I ON I.ItemId = CI.ItemId
WHERE   C.Node = @Node_Id
```

This query returns exactly what I want, but it's only a part of bigger query. What I need is to use the criteria api to create the same result: a list of items with a given root ID (keeping the tree structure is not needed - it's the result of the "search" command, so just a collection of entries is required). Unfortunatelly I'm not NHibernate expert, so... any guides, ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you keep your SQL as-is. Don't even try doing that with Criteria.

Comment: I would, but as I said this is only a part of bigger processing and the rest uses criteria api. As far as I know it's not possible to mix plain sql ad criteria api in a single query (or not?), so I have to find some way of adding this filter into existing code.

Comment: @user817409: it's not possible to mix them in the same query, that's correct. But none of the native NH APIs support recursive queries, so you're stuck with SQL if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix SQL with criteria but not a cte as the `Expression.SQL()` puts the relevant sql in the WHERE clause... that said you can apply a two step process in your method:

execute the above recursive query in plain sql and it returns an Id of some sort (`c.Child`) and that product you can use with Restrictions.Eq if it is a single row, or Restrictions.In for a returned collection of ids.